# C++/CX - Check the type of an object?

Tags: types, windows-runtime, c++-cx

Is it possible to check the type of an object in C++/CX ?

I have a Vector of objects which derive from ICustomObject and as I enumerate the objects from the Vector, i'd like to know what the actual object type is. This is so that I know what properties of that object should be accessible to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this works just fine!

```
 Type^ meh = element->GetType();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic_cast - if the object is an object of MyObjectType, the result will be non null, if it's another type, the result will be nullptr.

Comment: Actually, it appears to be even easier... Type^ meh = element->GetType();