# How to check the type of an Object (including boxed scalar) in WinRT + C++/CX

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I have a C# function that returns an arbitrary Object (which can be a string, a dictionary, or any other class, including boxed numbers) e.g.

```
public static Object foo() {
  return 3.14;
}
```

When called from C++/CX on WinRT how can I know check the type of the returned object? I don't understand why this doesn't work:

- `if (result->GetType() == String::typeid)`
- `if (result->GetType() == double::typeid)`
- `if (result->GetType()->Equals(double::typeid))`

This does work for "real" objects:

```
auto temp = dynamic_cast<String^>(result);
if (temp) {
    ...
}
```

But I can't figure out how to handle the boxed number case since `dynamic_cast<Double>(result)` is not possible.

PS: I saw this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027483/c-cx-check-the-type-of-an-object) but it doesn't cover the boxed number case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of Googling I found this solution but I have no idea if that's proper:

```
    Object^ result = ...

    if (dynamic_cast<IBox<double>^>(result)) {
        auto value = safe_cast<double>(result);
        ...
    }

    auto string = dynamic_cast<String^>(result);
    if (string) {
        auto value = _PlatformStringToString(string);
        ...
    }
```